# ¿Como devolver este XML en servicio web asmx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .asmx

Cómo devuelvo la siguiente estructura de xml en este servicio web, veo que es por el `public string()` pero no existe un `public xml()`? o cual es su equivalencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetVehicles(string user, string userPass) {
    string result = null;

    if (ValidClient(user, userPass) == false)
    {
        result = "<Response>" +
            "<CodigoResultado>"+ "401" + "<CodigoResultado>"+
            "<Descripcion>"+ "El usuario no se encuentra autenticado"+"<Descripcion>" +
            "</Response>";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
              return null;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Si observas tu respuesta ya te devuelve un tipo xml y le estas diciendo que es un objeto string solo especifica que tipo de objeto quieres devolver algo como validacionRespuesta y este objeto con dos propiedades Codigo resultado y descripcion

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @MiguelZarate pues tengo algo de idea de lo que debería hacer, pero no se como hacerlo, como devolver ese objeto que mencionas osea no so como buscar en SanGoogle, por otro lado lo que quiero principalmente es eliminar la etiqueta <string>.

Comment: Como dice @MiguelZarate el `response` que devuelves ya es un xml. La etiqueta `<string>` pues por que el `GetVehicles` especificas que retornara una cadena la cual manual mente la colocas con el formato de xml, Pero sigue siendo una cadena.

Comment: Create una clase nueva y agregale dos propiedades `CodigoResultado` y otra `Descripcion` y la retornas en el metodo `GetVehicles`.

Comment: Gracias @OrlandoDeLaRosa, tienes algún fragmento de código que me de la idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu respuesta la puedes especificar mediante una Respuesta Validacion

a continuacion el pseudo codigo, esto porque tu funcion es obtener vehiculos, pero solo estas respondiendo la validacion, aqui tienes que especificar tambien la respuesta vehiculos o cambiarle el titulo a tu metodo.

```
 public class RespuestaValidacion
{
  public string CodigoResultado {get;set}
  public string Descripcion {get;set;}
}

[WebMethod]
public RespuestaValidacion GetVehicles(string user, string userPass) {
    string result = null;

    if (ValidClient(user, userPass) == false)
    {
    return new RespuestaValidacion(){"401","El usuario no se encuentra autenticado"}
}
 else
   ...
}
```

Comment: Eso era justo lo que necesitaba, ya empiezo a comprender un poco más este mundo de C#. Gracias @Miguel Zarate. Sólo faltaba ponerle: `return new RespuestaValidacion() { CodigoResultado = "401", Descripcion = "El usuario no se encuentra autenticado" };`

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener una estructura debes responder con una class como respuesta

Para eso defines la clase

```
public class Response
{
    public int CodigoResultado {get;set;}
    public string Descripcion {get;set;}
}
```

Y luego la usas en el webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public Response GetVehicles(string user, string userPass) {
    string result = null;

    if (!ValidClient(user, userPass))
    {
        return null;
    }

    retunr new Response()
    {
        CodigoResultado = 401,
        Descripcion = "El usuario no se encuentra autenticado"
    };

}
```